# Rails jquery chosen : TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I added this gem in my gemfile

```
gem 'chosen-rails', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.2'
```

now whenever I add this line in my application.js file `//= require chosen-jquery` I get error

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

and the error point to this line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

my application js file looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
//= modul_steps
//= require chosen-jquery
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. All I did is add the gem file and require it in application.js. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `//= modul_steps`

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with `//= modul_steps`. Because I just added select2 and it is working fine. But chosen jquery is not working for some reasons

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Have you added `*= require chosen` in application.css

Comment: @asdlfkjlkj , i tried to set up your problem on my local, but everything seems work well.
Can you post more code and the stack trace (including the rails version)?